# OAuth Authentication fails with error AADSTS65005 in ios Xamarin

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios, adal

The authentication used to work for us earlier but has stopped suddenly.
We have an app built in `Xamamin iOs` and have registered the application in Azure AD account, provided the `ClientID` and redirect URL as specified. But it throws an error when *"authContext.AcquireToken"* is being called

> Exception: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS65005: The client application has requested access to resource 'example.com/'. This request has failed because the client has not specified this resource in its requiredResourceAccess list.
>
> Trace ID: ea22c27c-9913-4423-92dc-6fff1cf9904d
>
> Correlation ID: 4c19258b-2391-4585-911e-853157dde073
>
> Timestamp: 2017-01-24 09:28:49Z

Code we are using to acquire token:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, new Uri(returnUri),
            new PlatformParameters(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController));
```

And for authority variable, we are using "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common" to authenticate. We also tried "https://login.windows.net/common" but with no luck.

Has there been any microsoft updates lately which could have stopped this code from running?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, you were trying to access the resource `example.com/`.
However this resource was removed to grant to that app.

To fix this issue, you can login the [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com) to grant this resource to your app again like figure below(switch your Azure AD->App registrations->You App->Settings->Required permissions->Add):
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I think it has something to do with office 365 updates - it gives the above "AADSTS65005" error if I run the app but if I change the redirect URI,it opens the page in my app, instead of redirecting. The same used to work earlier for me. I also tried creating a new client native app, but it returned me the same error. What could be wrong?

Comment: What's the resource you are accessing? And would you mind sharing the screenshot about how the permission you have granted?

Comment: I am trying to access my sharepoint site as resource. Here is the link to screenshot - https://www.dropbox.com/s/557gmo7zti6vbez/ADAuthentication.png?dl=0

Comment: What's the exact **resource** value you used to acquire the token? Are you able to access this SharePoint site successfully? You can also use the [Discovery Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/discovery-service-rest-operations) to find all the available service.

Comment: I am trying to access my o365 sharepoint intranet site i.e. companyname.sharepoint.com as resource and yes I am able to access that site. But if I enter any other URL as a resource, it gives me an error saying "The application named "xyx" was not found in the tenant named 'guid'.  This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant". Also, I have created a native client app for this ios app; where I did not find application permissions. Do I need to register it as a web app?

Comment: Are you able to find the service resource id through the [Discovery Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/discovery-service-rest-operations)?

Comment: No,I am not sure about how to use discovery service for fetching list items, I would be trying that now. Basically, I would want to fetch, query and update list items.. will that be possible using the discovery service? Also, one thing that I noticed was, I was able to get an access token for graph API. But with graph API, I don't get my list items which results in InvalidAudience error. Probably, because it doesn't expose list items.

Comment: The Discovery Service is only used for find the correct resource id. Did **graph API** means Microsoft Graph? What's the request you were querying and what's the audience in the access token?

Comment: Oh Thanks. https://<companyname>.sharepoint.com/  and https://<companyname>-my.sharepoint.com/ are two resource ids found through discovery service, now AcquireTokenAsync works for https://<companyname>-my.sharepoint.com/  but not for https://<companyname>.sharepoint.com/ . Yes, by graph API I meant Microsoft Graph but as it does not expose any APIs for working on lists and list items, I get an error when I try to access the getlist API with the token received. For the audience, it is an office 365 user / AzureAD user. The users are also site collection admins on the sharepoint site.

Comment: Any ideas Fei Xue?

Comment: Finally got it resolved. There was an app in azure which was using my sharepoint site as its App URL which was in turn blocking and giving the above error. Never realized azure redirected that request to the app internally :)