# Best way to authenticate Office 365 users in Xamarin app and get data from SharePoint (office 365) in the app

Tags: c#, sharepoint, xamarin.ios, office365, sharepoint-online

We are developing a Xamarin IOS app and we want to get data from SharePoint and push data to SharePoint. Also when user opens the app we want that users to be authenticated by Office 365 as Office 365 users will be using the app. What could be the best approach to do this?

Thanks,
Anna Jhaveri

Comment: You could auth against AAD (Azure active directory).

Comment: I have read there are many ways using azure active directory, use SharePoint rest api and pass the token obtained using ADAL method or use MSAL or Microsoft graph, but the SharePoint api for graph is still in beta. We have already tried using ADAL but its not working for us, issue posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824862/oauth-authentication-fails-with-error-aadsts65005-in-ios-xamarin. So i was just thinking whether we are on right path or there are other ways

Comment: Anyone, any ideas? Your views are appreciated.